# How to dynamically generate HTML with languages like C, C++, Java?

Tags: java, c++, html, c, web-services

I want to create a website using HTML and the languages that i am most familiar with like C, C++, and Java in order to generate dynamic content. I am aware of the framework Django for Python which lets you do that(i think?) I know of the Common Gateway Interface/and FastCGI for C/C++/Java that lets me do just what i want. I think JavaEE/Servlet also lets me do what i want with Java. My question is are there any other more commonly(keyword: ***popular***) used tools to let me do what i want for C, C++, and Java? I am new to web development so i do not know where to start, i want to become familiar with the technology used to develop C, C++ and/or Java programs for the web.

Comment: As for the Java, you could take a look at [JSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces).

Comment: With the speed of development available with languages like C#, PHP, Python, and Java (just to name a few), C/C++ is rarely used for web programming these days.  If you want to learn web development, pick one of those languages and you'll be able to find a ton of books and examples on creating dynamic websites using them.  You will also want to learn Javascript, Ajax, and JQuery.

Comment: I've seen a lot of top websites doing back-end partly in C/C++ so i'm not sure this is true.

Comment: Your question title is a little unclear - you say you want to *communicate between* HTML and other languages, but from the question content it seems like you actually want to *generate* HTML from other languages.

Comment: I suppose that is what i really meant. I want to create dynamic webpages depending on what happens in the back-end with my programs running. Like a shopping website where someone purchases an item(transaction, updating done in C, C++, or Java for example) and the webpage changes depending on the result. I'm assuming i would also need to know some CSS, Javascript and AJAX to make this work.

Comment: Ok I edited your question title to be more accurate. You don't necessarily have to learn those things as some frameworks will abstract it away (e.g. in mine and abden003's answers). However it's probably a good idea anyway (I personally wouldn't like to generate code that I am not capable of understanding).

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak about Java, but I would take a look at [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org).  This open source framework does a good job of allowing you to keep HTML and data generation code separate. Using things like Servlets and JSP are also commonly used for what you are trying to do. Try googling a little more, there are plenty of resources out there to learn web development.

Answer (score 0):

A framework usually creates all the HTML, CSS, and Javascript code (the building blocks of a website) for you (no need to write it, it has been abstracted). Some C++ web frameworks are:

- [cppCMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CppCMS)
- [Poco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POCO_C%2B%2B_Libraries)
- [Tntnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tntnet)
- [Wt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wt_%28web_toolkit%29)

Google App Engine has a version in Go language which is a language developed by Google and is statically-typed with syntax loosely derived from that of C.  Java has alot more web framework that are more popular and widely used.  I personally have been using the Java web framework Vaadin.

Here is a comical article on frameworks: http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.219431

Comment: is CGI or FastCGI a lesser form of a framework?

Comment: Note: POCO is more of a networking (and other things) framework which will give you access to things such as TCP/IP and the HTTP protocol rather than a higher level dynamic content generating API.

Comment: CGI and FastCGI are not frameworks, it is a protocol for interfacing interactive programs with a web server.  Now a framework might INCLUDE FastCGI within it.  The whole purpose of a framework is abstraction.  It is meant to make web development faster and more capable.  For example instead of worrying about the html, css, and javascript you worry about the logic and features of your site (like what to do when someone presses a button).

Comment: So frameworks do HTML, CSS, and javascript to the point where you don't actually need to know the language?

Comment: Yes, I made a website without writing a single code of html, css, or javascript.  If you want to customize your site though you might need to go in and change the CSS, sometimes the frameworks offers ways to do this easily.  Sometimes the theme of the framework is versatile where you might not need to do this, but sometimes there are somethings that you do not like the look of.  In those cases you would need to change the CSS.  When this happens just google what you wanna do and usually you'll find a snippet of CSS that is the same or near identical to what you need.

Comment: @user2644819 By the way, the list of C++ frameworks in this answer was pulled off Wikipedia, and you can view the full page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks), if you want to see examples for other languages.